# Admob banner not sticking to bottom of uitableview swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, admob

I've added admob banners into my app which are working fine except when my rows in the tableview don't completely fill up the screen. The banners then just sit under the last row, I'd like to force them to stay "stuck" to the bottom of the screen. Thanks very much.

[image]

[image]

```
//MARK: Properties
// Ad banner and interstitial views
    var adMobBannerView = GADBannerView()
    let ADMOB_BANNER_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxx"

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Init AdMob banner
        initAdMobBanner()
        }


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return adMobBannerView
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return adMobBannerView.frame.height
    }

// MARK: -  ADMOB BANNER
    func initAdMobBanner() {

        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            // iPhone
            adMobBannerView.adSize =  GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 320, height: 50))
            adMobBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height, width: 320, height: 50)
        } else  {
            // iPad
            adMobBannerView.adSize =  GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 468, height: 60))
            adMobBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height, width: 468, height: 60)
        }

        adMobBannerView.adUnitID = ADMOB_BANNER_UNIT_ID
        adMobBannerView.rootViewController = self
        adMobBannerView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(adMobBannerView)

        let request = GADRequest()
        adMobBannerView.load(request)
    }


    // Hide the banner
    func hideBanner(_ banner: UIView) {
        banner.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width/2 - banner.frame.size.width/2, y: view.frame.size.height - banner.frame.size.height, width: banner.frame.size.width, height: banner.frame.size.height)
        banner.isHidden = true
    }

    // Show the banner
    func showBanner(_ banner: UIView) {
        banner.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width/2 - banner.frame.size.width/2, y: view.frame.size.height - banner.frame.size.height, width: banner.frame.size.width, height: banner.frame.size.height)
        banner.isHidden = false
    }

    // AdMob banner available
    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ view: GADBannerView) {
        // Reposition the banner ad to create a slide up effect
        let translateTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: adMobBannerView.bounds.size.height)
        adMobBannerView.transform = translateTransform
        showBanner(adMobBannerView)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.adMobBannerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }

    // NO AdMob banner available
    func adView(_ view: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        // Reposition the banner ad to create a slide up effect
        let translateTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: adMobBannerView.bounds.size.height)
        adMobBannerView.transform = translateTransform
        hideBanner(adMobBannerView)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.adMobBannerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }
```

I've used these 2 tutorials:

https://www.appcoda.com/google-admob-ios-swift/

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-add-admob-banner-ads-to-your-ios-swift-app--cms-27403

Comment: Where are you adding your adMob Banner, Inside or Outside of the tableView?

Comment: I'm adding it as a subview, as the view is a uitableview I'm guessing inside? Ideally don't want have to make a new view and add a tableview to it.

Comment: Make sure, You need to add your adMobBannerView, Outside of tableView.                  For Example : `view.addSubView(adMobBannerView)`

Comment: Sorry, in that case I have added it outside my tableview, see my code snippet I attached.

Comment: After adding adMobBannerView outside tableView, What issue you facing, And share latest screen shot of position of BannerView

Comment: Screenshots attached, the issue is if there aren't enough rows in the table the ad sits under the last row instead of sticking to the bottom of the screen, eg a search with only 2 results

Comment: Where You want to set adMobView? In the last cell of tableView or Bottom of your main View.

Comment: at the bottom of the main view

Comment: Than simple add your view, bottom of Main view.  Like this > view.addSubView(adMobBannerView)

Comment: But make sure, Set frame of bannerView properly

Comment: Thanks, check my code above, I've done that but it's still showing in the last cell instead of the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have spent ages trying what people have suggested and continued googling. This problem has been bugging me for 2 weeks and I'm glad to say I have solved it with one line.

As I embedded the tableview within a navigation controller (see here if you don't know how to do that: [Apple tute table navigation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1) ) I had seen people mention adding subviews to the navigation controller "ontop" of the UITableViewController.

So I simply changed this one line:

```
view.addSubview(adMobBannerView)
```

to

```
self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(adMobBannerView)
```

I also removed the following as the banner ad was no longer part of the uitableviewcontroller:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return adMobBannerView
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return adMobBannerView.frame.height
    }
```

The rest of my code is still used for banner placement, animation etc and it's all still applied and working flawlessly.

I hope this helps others who have the same problem.

Oh, and if you need to remove this subview it's also a one liner -

```
admobBannerView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, iPhone and iPad comes in various dimensions in both width and height of the screen.

In code, you are providing constant height, width and placement of ADMOB frames and will work well in iPhone  for 5,5s and SE version,

for rest of upper screens models, You have to set them dynamically,

To do the same here is my solution:

I think you have to update the method to initiate the frame and place of the ad mob

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        // iPhone
        adMobBannerView.adSize =  GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
        adMobBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height - 50.0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 50)
    } else  {
        // iPad
        adMobBannerView.adSize =  GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 60))
        adMobBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height - 60.0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 60)
    }
```

In this, I am first getting the device height and width from view itself.

Answer (score 0):

**You can Do it Like below Image. add bannerview in Bottom of View. you added banner in footerview of tableView.** [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQcbV.png]